# Accessing Ajax Response JSON Data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use an AJAX request to get the data from the backend when user select an option from a dropdown menu.

```
    $('#adSpace').change(function () {
        var sel_opt = $(this).val();

        alert(sel_opt);

        var location = null;
        var width = null;
        var height = null;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "advertisements-controller.php",
            data: {
                action: "getDimension",
                location: sel_opt
            },
            success: function (response) {

                location = response.banner_location;
                alert(location);


            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

       });
```

Now i'm getting the data from backend in JSON format like below:

```
[{"banner_location":"category_group_sidebar","banner_width":250,"banner_height":225}]
```

I want to access the values of `banner_location`, `banner_width`, `banner_height`  by assigning those to javascript variables but I'm failing to do it. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You are declaring the `location` in the wrong spot. It needs to be declared inside the `success` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
location = response[0].banner_location;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response comes in the form of an array: `[...]`. That means you can access the first array item by using the index. Also if there are multiple objects you can iterate `response` with `forEach` or jQuery's `each`(`$(response).each`).

```
response[0].banner_location
```

Comment: Yeah i seemed to have missed that.
Now i want to show a message using : 

 if (sel_opt == 'category_sidebar') {
                $('#message').html('<p>Please select an image with +width+  * +height+ dimension</p>');
            }
Can you giva an idea?

Answer (score 0):

`response` is an array of json. In order to access the json you need to firsr access the index of the array which is done by `array[indexNumber]` then the key of the json.
In your case it will be `response[0].banner_location`

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON array or a JSON object. There are arrays and objects. JSON is a string.